# Generic Web.Config Rewrite to remove query strings and add url seo slug

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, seo, web-config, url-rewrite-module

I have the following URL Rewrite I am trying to create.

```
<rule name="Imported Rule 3">
    <match url="^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)" ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:0}/{R:1}.aspx?p={R:2}&title={R:3}" appendQueryString="true" />                  
</rule>
```

I want the following urls to rewrite to the following.

```
/Catalog/Product/1/Title-Description
```

To

```
/Catalog/Product.aspx?pid=1&title=Title-Description
```

And

```
/Events/Detail/1/Today
/Events/Detail.aspx?pid=1&title=Title-Description
```

Basically I want the write to be generic and apply to multiple scenarios. 
Anytime there is a url with 4 slashes, I want the rewrite rule to pick it up and convert it to the url.

So event a url of

1/1/1/1 would be valid.

Which would convert to

/1/1.aspx?pid=1&title=1

Just to give you an example.

I don't want to have to write a separate rewrite for each scenario.

However the above rewrite I wrote keeps throwing an error on the server and I can't seem to find out what is wrong with my syntax. The server gices a generic 500 error so I can't narrow it down.

I'm fairly certain the issue is with the action tag,

I've written it as

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:0}/{R:1}.aspx?p={R:2}&title={R:3}" appendQueryString="true" />
```

and

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}/{R:2}.aspx?p={R:3}&title={R:4}" appendQueryString="true" />
```

Neither option works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are a few problems. The first being the use of {R:0} as you already found out yourself. `{R:0}` matches the entire URL as `{R:1}`, `{R:2}`, etc. matches the fragments. So in this case you must use `{R:1}`, `{R:2}`, etc.

Another problem is that you might have made a mistake to use `?p={R:3}` instead of `?pid={R:3}`. Finally and probably the reason for the 500 error is that you have not properly XML encoded the ampersand in the `&title` which should be `&amp;title`.

I think the following should work:

```
<rule name="Imported Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}/{R:2}.aspx?pid={R:3}&amp;title={R:4}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Perfect, that fixed the issue. I also had to add some conditions to prevent actual files on the server from being detected by the rewrite.      

   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
   <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" negate="true" pattern="(.*).aspx" />
    <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.ashx$" /><add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.axd$" />
    </conditions>